# IEnumerable.Count() or ToList().Count

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I got List of objects of my own class which looks like:

```
public class IFFundTypeFilter_ib
{
    public string FundKey { get; set; }
    public string FundValue { get; set; }
    public bool IsDisabled { get; set; }
}
```

The property `IsDisabled` is set by doing query `collection.Where(some condition)` and counting the number of matching objects. The result is `IEnumarable<IFFundTypeFilter_ib>` which does not contain property Count. I wonder, what would be faster.

This one:

```
collection.Where(somecondition).Count();
```

or this one:

```
collection.Where(someocondition).ToList().Count;
```

Collection could contains few objects but could also contains, for example 700. I am going to make counting call two times and with other conditions. In first condition I check whether FundKey equals some key and in the second condition I do the same, but I compare it with other key value.

Comment: That depends entirely on what `collection` actually is. You can also just _not_ count twice, but store that number.

Comment: I can't because at second call I will check other condition.

Comment: @CodeCaster What type of collection doesn't matter here. I guess you overlooked the where condition in question.

Comment: It would be better just to loop through and have an incrermenter that you increase every time the condition is met.

Comment: `Where` produces lazy enumerable, regardless of the type of source collection. `ToList` in this case must iterate through that enumerable. Comparing these lines, the second one is slower. But it doesn't clear for me, what OP means by " I am going to make counting call two times", especially, "I can't because at second call I will check other condition". @PawełMikołajczyk: could you post, what **exactly** are you going to do?

Comment: @Bauss no, that's exactly what Count() does.

Comment: Well, what is faster when you count the dollar bills in your pocket?  A: count them off one by one, B: buying a new wallet, making a photo copy of every bill, putting the copy in the new wallet and then count them?

Comment: `ToList` is redundant and needlessly time-consuming (if you're only interested in the count), although the effect will be somewhat mitigated because `Count` is a instance property of `List<T>` and doesn't require re-enumeration.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You asked:

> I wonder, what would be faster.

Whenever you ask that you should actually time it and find out.

I set out to test all of these variants of obtaining a count:

```
var enumerable = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000);
var list = enumerable.ToList();

var methods = new Func<int>[]
{
    () => list.Count,
    () => enumerable.Count(),
    () => list.Count(),
    () => enumerable.ToList().Count(),
    () => list.ToList().Count(),
    () => enumerable.Select(x => x).Count(),
    () => list.Select(x => x).Count(),
    () => enumerable.Select(x => x).ToList().Count(),
    () => list.Select(x => x).ToList().Count(),
    () => enumerable.Where(x => x % 2 == 0).Count(),
    () => list.Where(x => x % 2 == 0).Count(),
    () => enumerable.Where(x => x % 2 == 0).ToList().Count(),
    () => list.Where(x => x % 2 == 0).ToList().Count(),
};
```

My testing code explicitly runs each method 1,000 times, measures each execution time with a `Stopwatch`, and ignores all results where garbage collection occurred. It then gets an average execution time per method.

```
var measurements =
    methods
        .Select((m, i) => i)
        .ToDictionary(i => i, i => new List<double>());

for (var run = 0; run < 1000; run++)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < methods.Length; i++)
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var gccc0 = GC.CollectionCount(0);
        var r = methods[i]();
        var gccc1 = GC.CollectionCount(0);
        sw.Stop();
        if (gccc1 == gccc0)
        {
            measurements[i].Add(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
        }
    }
}

var results =
    measurements
        .Select(x => new
        {
            index = x.Key,
            count = x.Value.Count(),
            average = x.Value.Average().ToString("0.000")
        });
```

Here are the results (ordered from slowest to fastest):

```
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| average |                          method                           |
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| 14.879  | () => enumerable.Select(x => x).ToList().Count(),         |
| 14.188  | () => list.Select(x => x).ToList().Count(),               |
| 10.849  | () => enumerable.Where(x => x % 2 == 0).ToList().Count(), |
| 10.080  | () => enumerable.ToList().Count(),                        |
| 9.562   | () => enumerable.Select(x => x).Count(),                  |
| 8.799   | () => list.Where(x => x % 2 == 0).ToList().Count(),       |
| 8.350   | () => enumerable.Where(x => x % 2 == 0).Count(),          |
| 8.046   | () => list.Select(x => x).Count(),                        |
| 5.910   | () => list.Where(x => x % 2 == 0).Count(),                |
| 4.085   | () => enumerable.Count(),                                 |
| 1.133   | () => list.ToList().Count(),                              |
| 0.000   | () => list.Count,                                         |
| 0.000   | () => list.Count(),                                       |
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Two things come out that are significant here.

One, any method with a `.ToList()` inline is significantly slower than the equivalent without it.

Two, LINQ operators take advantage of the underlying type of the enumerable, where possible, to short-cut computations. The `enumerable.Count()` and `list.Count()` methods show this.

There is no difference between the `list.Count` and `list.Count()` calls. So the key comparison is between the `enumerable.Where(x => x % 2 == 0).Count()` and `enumerable.Where(x => x % 2 == 0).ToList().Count()` calls. Since the latter contains an extra operation we would expect it to take longer. It's almost 2.5 milliseconds longer.

I don't know why you say that you're going to call the counting code twice, but if you do it is better to build the list. If not just do the plain `.Count()` call after your query.

Comment: average time are sorted with seconds or milliseconds? Thanks.

Comment: It's `sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds`.

Comment: @Enigmativity why are you doing Count() on a List? List has a Count property. Don't need to use the Linq Count() method unless it does it anyway which I don't know but it would be a better comparison test if you do IEnumerable.Count() vs List.Count.

Comment: @David - LINQ's `Count()` method uses `.Count` under the hood for lists anyway. It's virtually no slower.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, materializing to a list will be less efficient.

Additionally, if you are using two conditions, there is no point in caching the result or materializing the query to a `List`.

You should just use the overload of `Count` which accepts a predicate:

```
collection.Count(someocondition);
```

As @CodeCaster mentions in the comments, it is equivalent to `collection.Where(condition).Count()`, but is more readable and concise.

Comment: `Where(x).Count()` does the same as `Count(x)`.

Comment: @CodeCaster What happens above the water also matters :)

Comment: @CodeCaster I mean that while the statements are equivalent in performance, the latter is more readable and concise.

Comment: I would disagree with @CodeCaster. They are **not** equivalent in performance either (otherwise why bother providing the overload) - `Where(x).Count()` involves creating and chaining 2 enumerators, while `Count(x)` needs only one.

Comment: @Ivan if it is on a collection from an ORM like Entity Framework, it will be translated to the same SQL. The overhead of instantiating another enumerator is negligible. As always with premature micro-optimizations: don't bother until it proves to be a problem; go for the most readable code.

Comment: @CodeCaster Fully agree for `IQueryable `and partially for `IEnumerable` and micro optimizations - some people even complaining why `IEnumerator` needs 2 virtual calls (`MoveNext` and `Current`) to achieve the goal :-)  But seriously, I don't see any other reason for providing all these predicate overloads for `Count`, `LongCount` and `Any`.

Answer (score 3):

Using it exactly this way

```
var count = collection.Where(somecondition).ToList().Count;
```

doesn't make sense - populating a list just to get the count, so using `IEnumerable<T>.Count()` is the appropriate way for this case.

Using `ToList` would make sense in a case you do something like this

```
var list = collection.Where(somecondition).ToList();
var count = list.Count;
// do something else with the list
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL behind pure `Count()` without `ToList()` is extremally straight and does not force any data transmission neccessary to populate a list.